# Conditionally retrieving associated many-to-many records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

There is a relationship of `many-to-many`. Model `A` and Model `B`. The association table is `A_B`. In   table A_B, there are four columns: `id`, `A_id`, `B_id`, `status`. For the status column, there are two possible values: `0` or `1`. Now I want to call `A.B` to get the `Bs` with status `1`. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a new association for the Bs with status 1. Add this to your A model

```
has_many  :active_Bs, :through => :a_bs, 
          :class_name => "AB", 
          :source => :b, 
          :conditions => ['a_b.status = ?', 1]
```